Migrating GCP projects from an organization to a personal GCP account
We have a GCP account which is linked to our domain using Google cloud identity (no Google workspace).
We are selling our domain name but want to keep the GCP projects (around 5) and billing account.
Is it possible to migrate the projects and billing account to a new personal GCP account?
Or is it only possible to migrate projects which are attached to an existing organisation to another organisation?
Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

You can only move projects from org to org. In that case, if you are selling your official domain, you can get another domain, create a Google Cloud org on this domain and then move your projects

Great thanks for confirming Guillaume. Will the billing account transfer also transfer the projects or do I have to do that separately? I think we have a shared networking project so hopefully I can transfer all projects without any issues.

Billing account is disconnected of the projects and org. You can keep them as is.

Thanks, I managed to migrate the billing account and projects in the end. A few hiccups with shared networking but manage to resolve them.
